# how to reshape data in r with reshape package

Tags: r, reshape

I have data that look like this:

```
Id    date         result
1     12/2/1997    1
1     04/5/2000    0
2     06/4/1998    1
2     18/6/1999    1
2     20/3/2000    0
```

And I want it to look like:

```
Id date.1    result.1 date.2     result.2 date.3    result.3
1  12/2/1997 1        04/5/2000  0        na        na
2  06/4/1998 1        18/6/1999  1        20/3/2000 0
```

Comment: thank for editing i try to ask from mobile phone and it all mass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
df$indx <- with(df, ave(seq_along(Id), Id, FUN=seq_along))
df1 <- reshape(df, idvar='Id', timevar='indx', direction='wide')
df1
#   Id    date.1 result.1    date.2 result.2    date.3 result.3
#1  1 12/2/1997        1 04/5/2000        0      <NA>       NA
#3  2 06/4/1998        1 18/6/1999        1 20/3/2000        0
```

#### Update

If you want to add  a new column using the `indx`

```
 df1$newCol <- tail(unique(df$indx), nrow(df1))
 df1
 #  Id    date.1 result.1    date.2 result.2    date.3 result.3 newCol
 #1  1 12/2/1997        1 04/5/2000        0      <NA>       NA      2
 #3  2 06/4/1998        1 18/6/1999        1 20/3/2000        0      3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = c("12/2/1997", 
"04/5/2000", "06/4/1998", "18/6/1999", "20/3/2000"), result = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("Id", "date", "result"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Was just going to post `reshape(getanID(mydf, "Id"), idvar = "Id", timevar = ".id", direction = "wide")`. +1

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks, I did thought about the `getanID`

Comment: Just wait until "data.table" v 1.9.8 comes out and you're able to do something like `dcast.data.table(getanID(mydf, "Id"), Id ~ .id, value.var = c("date", "result"))` :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto  That will be great.

Comment: can i add the max number from the indx to my data after reshape. so in the end i have other col with value 2 and 3.

Comment: @itayfriedman  Please check if the update is what you wanted.

Comment: @itayfriedman  You may have to add a space filler `NA` in that case, ie. `df1$newCol <- tail(c(NA,unique(df$indx)), nrow(df1))`.  This could be automated with a condition.

Comment: @akrun in my data set i end with 4 unique value and nrow = 5 it throw me error. in the end the last col value need to be (1,2,1,3,1)

Comment: @itayfriedman  But `c(1,2,1,3,1)` is only 3 unique values`.  Could you please show `dput` example in your post.